# the output of this code is 0, can someone explain it to me

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
int main() 
{
 int x = 2, y = 0;
 int z = (y++) ? y == 1 && x : 0; /* Need help here */
 printf("%d\n", z);
 return 0; 
}
```

need help on the 4th line. why is the output 0, need help plzzzzzzzz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP could easily research this code golf example himself.

Comment: Do you know how the ternary operator works?

Comment: Think of the value of `y`, and what "post-increment" and "ternary operator" do.

Comment: I want to say "Do your own homework", but it's pointlessly stupid homework, so I guess the appropriate advice is "Drop this class and take a better one."

Comment: @Yash If the code were `int z = 0 ? 1 : 0;`, what would `z` be?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve problems like these is by understanding operator precedence. Expand the lowest-precedence operators first, in this case the assignment and ternary operators:

```
int main() 
{
    int x = 2, y = 0;
    int z;

    if (y++) {
        z = y == 1 && x;
    } else {
        z = 0;
    }

    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0; 
}
```

The answer is already apparent here -- `y++` evaluates the value of `y` (which is `0`) first, and then increments it, so the condition evaluates to `0` and the `else` branch is taken, giving `z` a value of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

y++ is post increment 
try ++y